# PHP dependency injection with constructor arguments making testing difficult

Tags: php, dependency-injection, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to get a handle on some dependency injection best practices. I am trying to test a service class that is using the `braintree/braintree_php` composer library. Suppose i have a `BraintreeService` class like this:

```
namespace App\Service;

class BraintreeService
{
    /* @var Braintree_Gateway */
    private $gateway;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->gateway = new \Braintree_Gateway([
            'environment' => BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT,
            'merchantId' => BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID,
            'publicKey' => BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY,
            'privateKey' => BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY,
        ]);
    }

    /*
     * Generate a new client token from Braintree
     *
     * @return string $string
     */
    public function getClientToken() : string
    {
        return $this->gateway->clientToken()->generate();
    }
}
```

The usage of the class would then look like this:

```
$btService = new \App\Service\BraintreeService();
$token = $btService->getClientToken();
```

The obvious problem is that this service class is tightly dependent upon `Braintree_Gateway`. Thus, making unit testing `BraintreeService` difficult. To make testing easier, I would like to move `Braintree_Gateway` to a constructor argument. This would allow me to mock the `Braintree_Gateway` class in my unit test.

However, as i understand it, if i do this then the code would look like this:

```
namespace App\Service;

class BraintreeService
{
    /* @var Braintree_Gateway */
    private $gateway;

    public function __construct(Braintree_Gateway $gateway)
    {
        $this->gateway = $gateway;
    }

    /*
     * Generate a new client token from Braintree
     *
     * @return string $string
     */
    public function getClientToken() : string
    {
        return $this->gateway->clientToken()->generate();
    }
}
```

The usage of that class would then look like this:

```
$btService = new \App\Service\BraintreeService(
    new \Braintree_Gateway([
        'environment' => BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT,
        'merchantId' => BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID,
        'publicKey' => BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY,
        'privateKey' => BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    ])
);
$token = $btService->getClientToken();
```

I feel like this would get cumbersome if i use this service in multiple places throughout the code. I would love some advice on how better to handle the dependency while still being able to fully test my service class. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework or DI container?

Comment: Not at the moment, but not opposed to implementing a DI container if i can without using a whole framework. I've used Laravel and this stuff is easier there but unfortunately not able to move to Laravel in this scenario.

Comment: If not using a container, you could encapsulate your service creation in a Factory class

Comment: What would my testing then look like with that? Would i still be able to test `BraintreeService::getClientToken()`?

Comment: You would use the factory in your production code in order to reduce the hassle of instancing the service, but could instance it directly using a mock in testing. Although that particular method you mention is only testing the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Accept null as the default in your constructor:

```
public function __construct(Braintree_Gateway $gateway=null) { 
  if(!gateway) { 
    $gateway = new \Braintree_Gateway([
    'environment' => BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT,
    'merchantId' => BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID,
    'publicKey' => BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY,
    'privateKey' => BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    ]);
  }
}
```

This way you can override it for testing but leave it backwards compatible in production